# My Jtable Model doesnt make my boolean a checkbox

Tags: java, jtable, jcheckbox

sorry but I still don't get this thing from my database dont change to check box. it just show as true or false

```
try {

    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tblpdareenlist");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) viewRecordTable.getModel();
    int x = 0;

    String b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
    Boolean a;
    while (rs.next()) {
      a = rs.getBoolean("colAttend");
      b = rs.getString("colNr");
      c = rs.getString("colRank");
      d = rs.getString("colFName");
      e = rs.getString("colMName");
      f = rs.getString("colLName");
      g = rs.getString("colSN");
      h = rs.getString("colUnit");
      i = rs.getString("colETE");
      model.insertRow(x, new Object[]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i});
      x++;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Syntax Error\n" + e);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JTable` will display a check box for a column if the table model's `getColumnClass` method returns `Boolean.class` for that column<sup>[[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)</sup>. You are using the `DefaultTableModel` which only returns `Object.class` for any column. This model is just a very simple model, not the best for a *real* system, more for testing or very simple data.

The best is to implement your own `TableModel` returning the correct class for given column, e.g. extending the `AbstractTableModel`.

For **testing only** you can just extend the `DefaultTableModel` and override the `getColumnClass` method:

```
    var model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 3) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            if (col == 0) return Boolean.class;
            else return super.getColumnClass(col);
        }
    };
    var table = new JTable(model);
    model.insertRow(0, List.of(false, "false", 0).toArray());
    model.insertRow(1, List.of(true, "true", 1).toArray());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table);
```

Again, on the long run, for a real project, you will get stuck very soon with that solution - much better to implement a dedicated `TableModel`. A very simple (incomplete) example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var model = new MyTableModel();
    var table = new JTable(model);
    model.add(new MyData(false, "false", 0));
    model.add(new MyData(true, "true", 1));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table);
}

static final int FLAG = 0;
static final int NAME = 1;
static final int VALUE = 2;

private static class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();

    void add(MyData data) {
        list.add(data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        var data = list.get(row);
        switch(col) {
            case FLAG: return data.flag;
            case NAME: return data.name;
            case VALUE: return data.value;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("column " + col);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        switch(col) {
            case FLAG: return Boolean.class;
            case NAME: return String.class;
            case VALUE: return Integer.class;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("column " + col);
    }
}

private static class MyData {
    final boolean flag;
    final String name;
    final int value;
    MyData(boolean flag, String name, int value) {
        this.flag = flag;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

<sup>[1] [JTable Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)</sup>